# When using group by column i just want to show two of the values in that column

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test':[0,0,1,1,2,3],
               'ROI':[12,13,14,12,13,15]})
```

| Test | ROI |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 |
| 0 | 13 |
| 1 | 14 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 15 |

And I grouped them by the column test for the average of the ROI:

```
Group1 = df[["Test","ROI"]].groupby("Test").mean()
```

It gave me:

| Test | ROI |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 12.5 |
| 1 | 13.0 |
| 2 | 13.0 |
| 3 | 15.0 |

But I just want the average of the ROI of the Group, 0 and 3.
How can I do this?
I want this:

| Test | ROI |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 12.5 |
| 3 | 15.0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to select only the rows where `Test` equals either `0` or `3`, before applying [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
- Adding `as_index=False` returns a `df`, without it, you'll get a `pd.Series` with `Test` as the index.

```
res = df[df.Test.isin([0,3])].groupby("Test", as_index=False).mean()

print(res)

   Test   ROI
0     0  12.5
1     3  15.0
```